# Scanner.nextLine() throws NoLineFound only in console

Tags: java, gradle

I have a simple class Main,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

When I start it from IDEA, everything works fine, but when I start my application from the console - I get `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`

I use gradle, start with the gradle task

```
task runApplication(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn jar

    classpath += files(jar.getArchiveFile())
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    main = "com.Main"
}
```

Running on Windows 7 with Java 1.8

Comment: Thanks, but 
run {
    standardInput = System.in
} Gives me an error: Could not find method run() for arguments [.....]
Runnung gradle 5.5.1

Comment: Please adapt the solution to your particular file and naming convention. Put `standardInput = System.in` inside your `runApplication` task